# trying to instantiate enemies on a random position, but they spawn in the same box obj

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working with unity 2d and I'm trying to spawn enemies on a random place of placed box objects. However, when spawned enemy dies, it spawns on a wrong box spawner. Every enemy goes to the first box object position after they die. I already have tried to use transform and GameObject to distinguish boxes. How can I fix this so they can spawn on their own box object position?

Here's my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnerManager : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject enemy;
public GameObject box;

    public int count;
    public int MaxCount;
    public int enemyCount;
    public float spawnTime;
    public float curTime;
    private BoxCollider2D area;
    
    public static SpawnerManager _instance;
    
    void Start(){
        _instance = this;
    
        area = box.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    
        enemyCount++;
        Vector3 spawnPos = GetRandomPosition();
        GameObject instance = Instantiate(enemy, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
    }
    
    private void Update(){
        if(curTime >= spawnTime && enemyCount < MaxCount)
            SpawnEnemy();
    
        curTime += Time.deltaTime;
    }
    
    public void SpawnEnemy(){
        curTime = 0;
        enemyCount++;
        Vector3 spawnPos = GetRandomPosition();
        GameObject instance = Instantiate(enemy, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
    }
    
    private Vector2 GetRandomPosition(){
        Vector2 basePosition = box.transform.position;
        Vector2 size = area.size;
    
        float posX = basePosition.x + Random.Range(-size.x, size.x);
        
        Vector2 spawnPos = new Vector2(posX, basePosition.y);
    
        return spawnPos;
    }
}
```

Comment: `public static SpawnerManager _instance;` makes it seem like you're using this class as a singleton. If there is only one `SpawnerManager` or you are always accessing the same one  then there is only one `box` variable. Can you explain how you're using this? Maybe you want an array of boxes and then you choose which box and use the position relative to it.

Comment: I took it from a tutorial. When an enemy dies, it activates the line: SpawnerManager._instance.enemyCount--;
So let the spawner know that one more enemy is formed to spawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand correctly

- You have multiple instances of this script running at the same time
- Each has its own spawn box area
- Every time an enemy dies a new one should be spawned
- The new enemy should be spawned in the same box area it originally belonged to

#### Problem

You main issue is - as mentioned in the comments - this

```
public static SpawnerManager _instance;
```

There is no clear rule (except execution order you don't really handle but Unity) for predict which instance of this script will be the **last** one to run `Start` and overwrite this static field.

Then you say yourself every time an enemy dies you call

```
SpawnerManager._instance.enemyCount--;
```

=> Of course only this instance that happens to be the one assigned to `_instance` is aware of an enemy being removed and will always be the one to spawn a new enemy.

#### Solution

There are probably many ways

- You could continue using `static` but rather maintain a `Dictionary<GameObject, SpawnManager>` that keeps track which enemy instance belongs to which spawner

  Example

  ```
   public class SpawnerManager : MonoBehaviour
   {
       public GameObject enemy;

       public int count;
       public int MaxCount;
       public int enemyCount;
       public float spawnTime;
       public float curTime;
       // Use the correct type right away ;)
       public BoxCollider2D area;

       public static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<GameObject, SpawnerManager> spawnerByInstance = new Dictionary<GameObject, SpawnerManager>();

       void Start()
       {
           // Avoid double implementations -> you already have a method for this
           SpawnEnemy();
       }

       private void Update()
       { 
           // should handle the time first and then check if cooldown is over
           curTime += Time.deltaTime;

           if(curTime >= spawnTime && enemyCount < MaxCount)
           {
               SpawnEnemy();
           }
       }

       public void SpawnEnemy()
       {
           curTime = 0;
           enemyCount++;
           var spawnPos = GetRandomPosition();
           var instance = Instantiate(enemy, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity);

           // REGISTER THIS INSTANCE AND ITS OWNER MANAGER
           spawnerByInstance[instance] = this;
       }

       private Vector2 GetRandomPosition()
       {
           var basePosition = box.transform.position;
           var size = area.size;

           var posX = basePosition.x + Random.Range(-size.x, size.x);

           var spawnPos = new Vector2(posX, basePosition.y);

           return spawnPos;
       }
   }
  ```

  => when an enemy dies you can check which exact spawner should receive the `enemyCount--` and that one can then spawn a new one

  ```
   SpawnerManager.spawnerByInstance[enemyThatDied].enemyCount--;
  ```
- You could also have a dedicated component on your enemy prefab - I'd assume that's probably the case anyway - and at the moment of the spawn let the manager pass in a reference to itself to the new enemy instance

  Example on the enemy prefab

  ```
  public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
  {
      public SpawnerManager associatedSpawner;

      private void OnDestroy()
      {
          associatedSpawner.enemyCount--;
      }
  }
  ```

  Example manager script

  ```
   public class SpawnerManager : MonoBehaviour
   {
       // Use the according component type
       public Enemy enemy;

       public int count;
       public int MaxCount;
       public int enemyCount;
       public float spawnTime;
       public float curTime;
       public BoxCollider2D area;

       void Start()
       {
           SpawnEnemy();
       }

       private void Update()
       {
           curTime += Time.deltaTime;

           if(curTime >= spawnTime && enemyCount < MaxCount)
           {
               SpawnEnemy();
           }
       }

       public void SpawnEnemy()
       {
           curTime = 0;
           enemyCount++;
           var spawnPos = GetRandomPosition();
           var instance = Instantiate(enemy, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity);

           // PASS ON REFERENCE TO THIS SPAWNER
           instance.associatedSpawner = this;
       }

       private Vector2 GetRandomPosition()
       {
           var basePosition = box.transform.position;
           var size = area.size;

           var posX = basePosition.x + Random.Range(-size.x, size.x);

           var spawnPos = new Vector2(posX, basePosition.y);

           return spawnPos;
       }
   }
  ```

  => when the enemy dies it knows which manager it was spawned by and can tell this exact manager to `enemyCount--` so it knows to create a new one

There are many other options including events or instead of the reference pass in a callback method to be executed. It always comes down a bit to taste and the decision who should be responsible for what. Should the enemies know what they have to tell to the manager when they die? Or should the manager rather tell them? Or should the manager just know itself and only react to an enemy dying?

Comment: Your recommend was helpful! Now the code fully works like what I expected! Thank you!